# Express serving index.html from Angular html5 mode not working

Tags: angularjs, html, express

I'm trying to use html5 mode in Angular JS app for sake of SEO. However, I faced the problem for Express  serving index.html to request. The deep linking didn't work and cannot refresh page.

App.js

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));
app.use('/api', routesApi);

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
res.sendFile('./app_client/index.html', { root: __dirname });
console.log("send index");
});
```

I already try many researches from many sources, approach such as

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile('index.html');
 });
```

or

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client', 'index.html'));
 });
```

or

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
```

None seems to work. I know that something must be wrong in my code, but i don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer at lasts

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app_client/index.html');
}
```